# Is there any other way to create an exe file from a java source other than ant script

Tags: java, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

I need to create an exe file from my java source. My requirement is to use other ways except ant script. Is there any other way to create the exe file.

Comment: What is the source of such a question?  Are you looking to create an .exe?  What requirements do you have that eliminate ant as a viable or desired option?

Comment: I've heard that Launch4J (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) is pretty good

Comment: Also, have you googled?  A quick google search threw up a number of options including JSmooth, JEXECreator amongst others.

Comment: More Info on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be clear about your requirements.

There are various ways to create an EXE from Java. The exe could be native compiled or could be using JRE. GCJ is the example of native compiled exe and Launch4J is an example of exe which is using JRE.

Please refer to following link for more details:

[How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Answer (score 2):

You could investigate GCJ.  The advantage of GCJ is that it is creating a native binary; no JVM is required to run the resulting executable.

```
$ gcj --main=test -o test.exe test.java
```

If you are using Windows, you will probably need to install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to compile using GCJ.

Some more verbose tutorials:

- http://www.autexier.de/jmau/dev/gcj.html
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/40425-compiling-java-programs-natively-with-gcj/

GCJ-compiled applications are significantly larger than their Java-compiled counterparts.